# Problem on logarithmic equalites

Tags: logarithms

*I am trying to prove that:* $$y^z.z^y=z^x.x^z=x^y.y^x$$

Given that:
$${{x(y+z-x)}\over {log(x)}}={{y(z+x-y)} \over {log(y)}}={{z(x+y-z)} \over{log(z)}}$$

*I started to solve it as follows:*
$${{x(y+z-x)}\over {log(x)}}={{y(z+x-y)} \over {log(y)}}={{z(x+y-z)} \over{log(z)}}={1\over k} \tag{1}$$
*From here I did some minor manipulations  and got*
$$ {y.log(x)}=(y+z-x)k$$
$$\implies log(x^y)=k(y+z-x)\tag{2} $$

*Similarly,*
$$log(y^x)=k(z+x-y) \tag{3} $$
$$(2)+(3)$$

$$log(x^y.y^x)=k(2z) \tag{4}$$
*Again Using (1) and manipulating like before we end up with*

$$log(z^x.x^z)=k(2y) \tag{5}$$
$$log (y^z.z^y)=k(2x) \tag{6}$$
How do I proceed from here? If I put it such that equations (4),(5)and(6) have only$1 \over k$ on the RHS and then equate them I'd still have other terms in the denominator.If it were not for the remaining terms I could've taken their anti-logs. Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Please write well known functions (e.g. logarithm) like this `$\log x$` $\to\log x$ and not `$log x$` $\to log x$.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1654903p10483098 https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h311307p1679347 https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h431859p2441130 https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h146824p830969

Comment: I searched by [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7B%7Bx(y%2Bz-x)%7D%5Cover%20%7Blog(x)%7D%7D%3D%7B%7By(z%2Bx-y)%7D%20%5Cover%20%7Blog(y)%7D%7D%3D%7B%7Bz(x%2By-z)%7D%20%5Cover%7Blog(z)%7D%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is a very helpful platform. Will be using it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this very elementary:

Using $\log$ on the equation gives us
$$z\log(y) + y\log(z) = x\log(z) + z\log(x) = x\log(y) + y\log(x)$$

Multiplying with $${{x(y+z-x)}\over {\log(x)}}={{y(z+x-y)} \over {\log(y)}}={{z(x+y-z)} \over{\log(z)}}$$ leads to
\begin{align*}&\;zy(z+x-y) + yz(x+y-z) \\=&\;xz(x+y-z) + zx(y+z-x) \\=&\;xy(z+x-y) + yx(y+z-x)\end{align*}

which simplyfies to $$\iff 2xyz = 2xyz = 2xyz$$
and we are done.

And because all modifications were equivalent the initial equation holds.